# PHP URL that's identified by the ID?

Tags: php, javascript, hyperlink

I'm still learning to use PHP with MySQL tables and I'm sorry if this is a novice question but how would I change the dropdown code below to be able to insert normal a href links (with an image or text) that link to the playerMenu.php page? Here's the dropdown menu code I have:

```
<form action="playerMenu.php" method="get">
  <select id="players" name="selectvalue" onchange="showMe(this.value);">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
  <option value="4">D</option>
  </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<form>

<a href="#"onclick="document.location.href='playerMenu.php?electvalue='+document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML">Submit</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question isn't about PHP in any way, AFAIKT, it's about JS (and I don't mean this cruelly, but you should learn a bit more of that, too). Perhaps look into event listeners, and the `setAttribute('src','changeMe')` methods of DOM nodes.

Comment: use JQuery... Just wait a sec

Comment: To learn more JS is now on the agenda! :D Ideally I'd like to create the same function as above but with a row of A-Z images or text that lead to pages A,B,C,D and so on.  I've read somewhere else that it would be better to avoid JS because some prefer to keep it disabled?  I'm really not sure on the most efficient way, which is why I've asked for some expert advice.  It's just frustrating that I know precisely how I want the pages to work but clearly don't know enough yet. Haha! Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how using JQuery. It works! Try it out!

```
<!-- Your Form -->

<form>
  <select id="players" name="selectvalue" onchange="showMe(this.value);">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
  </select>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Submit">
<form>

<!-- Include JQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>  

var sub_link = "playerMenu.php?electvalue="

$("#button").click(function() {
    sub_link = sub_link + $("#players").find('option:selected').text();

    // Here's your link
    alert(sub_link);

    // And now we do a javascript redirect
    window.location.replace(sub_link);
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works perfectly! :) How would I add normal a href image or text links? Would I just include:

Comment: Since everything is done using JavasScript, your links are stored in  memory rather than displayed on screen. for links you can do `sub_link = "http://my-website"` or images `sub_link = "http://my-website.com/my-picture.jpg"`.

Comment: I'll be using your code above because I needed the Primary PHP to direct to each specific ID/Letter of the player menu but I was unsure on the most efficient way. Seeing an example is much easier to understand and learn.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP side, once you submit that form then the url will be

```
playerMenu.php?players=1&submit=Submit
```

If the option A was chosen. You can remove the onchange and onclick javascript, if this is what you want to achieve.

From there you have passed in the value of the players select box. You would want to then likely save this as a variable and what you want with the code. If you are doing something with your database then make sure to santize the variable as well.

Comment: Thanks. :) Yes, I'm using MySQL and each ID/Value that is selected directs to the playerMenu with players under each specific letter.

Comment: So if you don't want to use javascript/jquery then at the top of your page playerMenu.php, you have the following code: